# Rails POST not working on Heroku but works locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, post, heroku

I have an API that I use for an iPad app. The controller accepts json and returns json. POST requests work when I run the server locally and I use the ISO simulator but when I hit the POST request after I deploy to heroku all the params that I send over as JSON are nil.

Watching the heroku logs I get the following when making the request.

```
    at=info method=POST path=/note/update host=myapp.herokuapp.com fwd="174.50.210.40" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=755ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-04-11T16:51:30.907621+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-04-11T16:51:30.908272+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by MyAPIController#update_note as JSON
2013-04-11T16:51:30.908272+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"myapi"=>{}}
2013-04-11T16:51:30.908272+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 551ms
```

My action in my controller looks like this.

```
def update_note

    puts "debug note update #{ params[:note] }"

    uuid = params[:uuid]
    user = User.find_by_uuid(uuid)
    noteid = params[:note][:note_id] if params[:note][:note_id]

    if !user.nil?
      note = nil
        note = user.notes.find(noteid) if !noteid.nil?
        if !note.nil?
            user.notes.find(noteid) 
            note.update_attributes!(params[:note])
        else
            note = user.notes.build(params[:note])
        note.save
        end
        render :json => {:result => note}
    else
        render :json => {:error => "nope"}
    end
  end
```

my routs file has the following

```
match '/note/update'  =>  'myapi#update_note'
```

for you that are familiar with objective-c here is the code for making the request

```
NSDictionary *noteVo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:note->title, @"title", note->body, @"body", note->note_id, @"note_id", nil];

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[_dm getUser]->uuid, @"uuid", noteVo, @"note", true, @"remote", nil];

    NSError *writeError = nil;

    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&writeError];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                    [NSURL URLWithString:[BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:@"note/update"]] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody: jsonData];

    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Comment: Did you by any chance made some migrations and forgot to run them on heroku ? If so, remember to restart the instance after

Comment: That was it .... I feel like a huge idiot. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The reason I found it is that I made that mistake before, and more than once :D Glad your problem is solved anyway !

Answer (score 0):

I think your example is not complete (i can't see where the "myapi" params is set in your Obj-C code)

Have you tried to make a call using curl to your API on heroku ?

I think it would be easier to debug that way.